# How to autoselect a passed in date in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Im new to PHP so apologies if this is a simple question. Please could you tell me how to auto select a date drop down in PHP (uses 3 drop downs - day/month/year). This is what my PHP code looks like:

```
$s = '01/08/2014 11:00:02';
$date = strtotime($s);
$objectToParse->setDateReceived(date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $date));
$form = $this->createForm(new Type(), $objectToParse);
```

And then the form looks like:

```
class Type extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
    {
        $builder->add('dateReceived', 'date', array(
            'required'  => false
        )) 
    }
}
```

I expected a `\DateTime`. But at the moment I just receive a

> 500 Internal Server Error - TransformationFailedException error

Comment: It seems as you use a library to build and probably render your form. Can you tell us which one you use so that poeple with know-how in this library can help you?

Comment: I am using Symfony...

Answer (score 0):

On your class Type, add something like :

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\MyObject',
    ));
}
```

It makes the binding between the given entity (MyObject) and the form.

From [Forms (The Symfony Book) :](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) :

> Every form needs to know the name of the class that holds the
>   underlying data (e.g. Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task). Usually, this is
>   just guessed based off of the object passed to the second argument to
>   createForm (i.e. $task). Later, when you begin embedding forms, this
>   will no longer be sufficient. So, while not always necessary, it's
>   generally a good idea to explicitly specify the data_class option

Also, you need to give a DateTime to the setter `setDateReceived`. What you gives with the `date`function is a string.

What you need to do is :

```
$s = '01/08/2014 11:00:02';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y H:i:s', $s);
$objectToParse->setDateReceived($date);
```